# Best Practice to restrict function or class initialization in Test Environment only?

Tags: java

In general, there are prod and test environments. If I will like to enable some function/API/class that is only accessible in Test Environment, what should be the best way to achieve it?

Other than put if statement before it, is there any elegant way to do it in Java App?

Comment: This depends almost entirely on the tools or frameworks you're using. (For example, in Spring you would use profiles or similar features.)

Comment: Thank you. My framework is Guice. In that case, what will be the best way?